# list of .csv files in one specific directory

Tags: r, csv, data-science

I have `.csv` files in a directory (lets say `C:/Dowloads`). I am able to read all the files from that directory using the `list.files("path")`. But I am unable to read a specified number of files using a `for` loop. That is, lets say I have 332 files and I just want to read only files 1 to 10 or 5 to 10.

Here is an example:

```
files <- list.files("path")
files ## displays all the files.
```

Now for testing I did:

```
k <- files[1:10]
k
## here it displays the files from 1 to 10.
```

So I kept the same thing using a `for` loop, as I want to read files one by one.

```
for(i in 1:length(k)){
  length(i) ## just tested the length 
}
```

But it is giving as `NA` or `Null` or `1`.

Can any one explain how can I read specified `.csv` files using a `for` loop or any other way?

Comment: `i` is just a single number, so the length of `i` should always be `1`.  If you are getting something other than that (eg, `NA`), you will need to post a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536) for people to work with to figure out why. If you want to *read* files in a `for` loop, why don't you try `read.table(file=files[i])`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`list.files` return a character vector of class `character`. A character vector is a vector of strings (i.e. characters). The function `length` applied to a character vector `files` or a range of elements within the character vector `files[1:10]` or to a single element in a character vector `files[i]` will return the number of strings in that character vector, the number of strings in the range, or 1, respectively. Use `nchar` instead to get the number of characters for each element (each string) of the character vector. So:

```
path.to.csv <- "/path/to/your/csv/files"
files<-list.files(path.to.csv)
print(files)  ## list all files in path

k<-files[1:10]
print(k)      ## list first 10 files in path

for(i in 1:length(k)) {  ## loop through the first 10 files
  print(k[i]) ## each file name
  print(nchar(k[i])) ## the number of characters in each file name
  df <- read.csv(paste0(path.to.csv,"/",k[i]))  ## read each as a csv file
  ## process each df in turn here
}
```

Note that we have to `paste` the "path" to the file name in calling `read.csv`.

**EDIT:** I thought I add this as an alternative:

```
path.to.csv <- "/path/to/your/csv/files"
files<-list.files(path.to.csv)

for(iFile in files) {  ## loop through the files
  print(iFile) ## each file name
  print(nchar(iFile)) ## the number of characters in each file name
  df <- read.csv(paste0(path.to.csv,"/",iFile))  ## read each as a csv file
  ## process each df in turn here
}
```

Here, the `for` loop is over the collection (vector) of `files` so that `iFile` is the `i`-th file name.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `df` will get overwritten with each iteration

Comment: @user20650: yes, indeed. I'm assuming that he is to process each file in turn when he said "read files one by one." I edited the post to reflect this. The answer is not meant to be an "end-all,"  just enough to hopefully answer his question. I have no idea how he wants to process the data in each of those files.

Answer (score 4):

To read a specific number of files at a time you can subset your vector of files. First create a vector of your files, including a path:

```
f = list.files("/dir/dir", full.names=T, pattern="csv")
# nb full.names returns the full path to each file
```

Then, read each file to a separate list item (in this case, the first 10):

```
dl = lapply(f[1:10], read.csv)
```

Finally, have a look at list item 1:

```
head(dl[[1]])
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there's no reproducible example to work with.
Usually, when I have to do similar tasks, I do so:

```
files <- list.files(pattern='*.csv') # this search all .csv files in current working directory 
for(i in 1:length(files){
    read.csv(files[i], stringsAsFactors=F)
}
```

Your code is not working because you're testing the length of an index, not of the vector. Hope this helps